# Cheap programmable GPS unit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, low-power, gps, cellphone

I'm in the middle of installing GPS tracking into my car using the following guide:

http://gizmodo.com/5691724/how-to-track-your-vehicle-on-the-cheap

Though I'd like to build something a little more elegant.  Ideally my solution will have a programmable GPS unit and a sim card (cdma seems better than gsm tracking), with no unnecessary hardware. I'm hoping this will help keep the size, power consumption, and operating cost minimized, though I can only imagine that something like this would cost more than the $30 phone from the guide without good ol' economies of scale. Do you know of any way that I can build something like this on the cheap?

Comment: How cheap? You could build with a GPS module like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11058?), which is 50 USD

Comment: The problem is that the phone you link to is most likely discounted/subsidized/sold at a loss. It would be difficult to approach that cost without tremendous effort (which would fall under the NRE category instead of parts cost).

Answer (score 2):

I've used this [GPS module](http://adafruit.com/products/746) before.  It works well and is probably the cheapest one you will find.  How about using an old Android phone?  I know my phone has a security app that tracks it if it's lost.